# Disable html button on the value of select tag

Tags: html, jquery

I have a select tag containing 4 options and a button. I want if no option is selected from select tag then the button should be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some Jquery stuff for it. Just follow the codes.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$('#myDrpDown').change(function(){
if($(this).val() == "")
{
   $('#btn').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
else
$('#btn').removeAttr('disabled');
});

});
</script>
<select id="myDrpDown">
<option value = "">Select One option</option>
<option value = "1">Option1</option>
<option value = "2">Option2</option>
<option value = "3">Option3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="btn" disabled="disabled">
```

Answer (score -1):

Use javascript onChange function to disable the button

```
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Button" />
```

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select').change(function(){
        $('#button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
});
```

Comment: This disables the button when user selects any option... why would you want that?